# Left join results according to parameter value

Tags: sql-server, database

In my stored procedure I am trying to get the results of a query according to parameter. I have a main table "employee" and table "employee_process" which I make left join with the first one. 
In the results if the parameter's value is 0 I want to get everything from "employee" except the rows which are joined with "employee_process" and if the value is 1 I want to get only the rows which are joined between the two tables. Here is what I have now:

```
DECLARE @state int = 0

SELECT *
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee_process ep ON ep.employee_id = e.employee_id
--this below is what I want to achieve (but obviously this is not correct)
WHERE CASE WHEN @state = 0 THEN ep.employee_id IS NULL ELSE ep.employee_id IS NOT NULL
```

How can I achieve that I tried using something like that:

```
WHERE ( @state ^ ep.employee_id IS NOT NULL )
```

but with no luck.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rephrase your `CASE` expression as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee_process ep
    ON ep.employee_id = e.employee_id
WHERE
    @state = 0 OR ep.employee_id IS NOT NULL;
```

A `CASE` expression has to generate actual values, and not other expressions.  But, here we don't even need to use a `CASE` expression.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, it seems we should add another criteria to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    (@state = 0 AND ep.status <> 'employee_process') OR ep.employee_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I know the case is wrong I just wanted to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. 
The code you've provided works almost correct. In the case of state=0 it returns everything from employee table. I need it to return everything from employee except the employees who are in employee_process

Comment: @Binev I can't give you an exact update, because you never showed us table structure or data.  I made a guess as to what you want.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with
(@state = 0 AND ep.employee_id IS NULL) OR (@state = 1 AND ep.employee_id IS NOT NULL) but is there any better way to do this

Comment: sorry Im not sure if you mean `add` or `have` another criteria

Comment: @Binev What is wrong with that solution?  It seems reasonable to me.

Comment: yes it is good indeed just asking if there is more optimal way

Comment: Hey Tim, For start I don't know how you understand that question I wish OP post some sample data there to be sure what he want. Just one thing ... I think  the `AND ep.employee_id IS NULL`  is not necesary because you are in the other side of the `OR ep.employee_id IS NOT NULL;` So you already know is `NULL`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, I see it now.  It took approximately 3 minutes to understand your comment, if you were wondering.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I had rewrote it a few time because miss a few words  Sometimes the brain isn't well connected to the fingers

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza With regard to the second part of your question, as a matter of habit I ask for sample data if the OP seems to have left out some details.  Sort of like buying a vowel in Wheel of Fortune, minus the fact that SO doesn't have anything like Vanna White :-)

Comment: thank you for your help the effect is achieved. I should probably reevaluate the way I think of WHERE clause